# How can I make a subtotal for all of the products i have chosen/

Tags: python, python-3.x

A problem that I have faced is in the output for when the input for menu_choice is 7; when the person giving an input has chosen one of each , I want to be able to display all of the options along with their total price overall. I have tried to do this by setting up a trial dictionary (The first box of code) to be able to add dictionary values, and need to be able to set each dictionary with a price and its product and then add that to one final total.

```
dict1 = [{'ca':2, 'na':3},{'ca':3, 'na':4}]

final = {}
for d in dict1:
    for k in d.keys():
        final[k] = final.get(k,0) + d[k]

print (final)
```

```py
cpu = {
    1: ("AMD Ryzen 5 5600X", 190),
    2: ("AMD Ryzen 7 5800X", 260),
    3: ("AMD Ryzen 9 5900X", 350),
    4: ("AMD Ryzen 9 5950X", 500),
    5: ("Intel Core i5-12400F", 135),
    6: ("Intel Core i7-12700K", 350),
    7: ("Intel Core i9-12900k", 500)
}

gpu={
    1: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3050", 300),
    2: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060", 400),
    3: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3070", 600),
    4: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080", 900),
    5: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3090", 1500)
}

store = {
    1: ("Samsung 970 EVO plus", 100),
    2: ("Samsung 980 PRO", 300),
    3: ("Seagate Barracuda Compute", 50),
    4: ("Kingston A400", 25),
    5: ("Seagate Ironwolf PRO", 500)
}

ram = {
    1: ("Crucial BallistiX", 40),
    2: ("Corsair Vengance Pro RGB", 80),
    3: ("Tiden Z RGB", 152),
    4: ("G.Skills Ripjaws V", 262),
    5: ("ADATA XPG LANCER RGB", 300)
}

cooler = {
    1: ("NZXT Kraken X53", 100),
    2: ("Noctua NHD-15", 90),
    3: ("ASUS ROG StiX", 240),
}

cases = {
    1: ("NZXT H510 ELITE", 150),
    2: ("Lian LI 011 Dynamic", 208),
    3: ("Corsair Carbide", 50)
}

def choice( menu ):
    for k,v in menu.items():
        print( f"{k}: {v[0]} \u00a3{v[1]}" )
    val = int(input("Make your choice by number:" ))
    print( f"You have chosen the {menu[val][0]} for \u00a3{menu[val][1]}" )


menu_choice=input("What would you like to buy today? [1: CPU's] [2: GPU's] [3: Storage] [4: RAM] [5: CPU Cooler] [6: Cases] [7: One of each] [Type the number that you want.]: ")

if menu_choice not in "12345678":
    print("You did not choose something or put in the wrong number.")
    exit()

if menu_choice in "17":
    print("Choose your CPU.:")
    c = choice(cpu)
if menu_choice in "27":
    print("GPU's, press enter to go to the next product:")
    c = choice(gpu)
if menu_choice in "37":
    print("Storage, press enter to go to the next product:")
    c = choice(store)
if menu_choice in "47":
    print("RAM, press enter to go to the next product:")
    c = choice(ram)
if menu_choice in "57":
    c = choice(cooler)
if menu_choice in "67":
    c = choice(cases)
```

Comment: What does this have to do with GDB (the GNU Debugger)?

Comment: `if menu_choice == ["1","7"]:` should be `if menu_choice in ["1","7"]:`

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and focus your question on one issue at a time

Comment: i am making it on GDB compiler

Comment: @MaxStrongman -- GDB is not a compiler.  It's a debugger.

Comment: I can't understand the question. "I am trying to figure out a way for the input to be either 1 or 7" What is "the input"? Why should it be one of those two things, and not anything else? What does that have to do with **any** of the code shown? Please read [ask] and [mre], forget about your existing code and write **short, new** code **from scratch, that demonstrates the problem directly**. Make sure that someone else can see the problem by copying and pasting that code. Make sure to explain: what happens when the code runs? What should happen instead? How is that different?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -1):

Consider this kind of data-driven design instead.  Notice how all the repetitive code is gone, and when you switch this to using a real database to store the items, you don't have to rewrite everything:

```
import time
import sys
Username=input("Enter Username: ")
Password=input("Enter Password: ")
User_Check=input("Enter User Name: ")
Pass_Check=input("Enter User Password: ")

if User_Check!=Username or Pass_Check!=Password:
    print("Incorrect Password/Username ")
    exit() # Ends the program

print("You have been logged in")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------")
print("        Your TechZilla Account has been registered")
print("--------------------------------------------------------------")

cpu = {
    1: ("AMD Ryzen 5 5600X", 190),
    2: ("AMD Ryzen 7 5800X", 260),
    3: ("AMD Ryzen 9 5900X", 350),
    4: ("AMD Ryzen 9 5950X", 500),
    5: ("Intel Core i5-12400F", 135),
    6: ("Intel Core i7-12700K", 350),
    7: ("Intel Core i9-12900k", 500)
}

gpu={
    1: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3050", 300),
    2: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060", 400),
    3: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3070", 600),
    4: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3080", 900),
    5: ("Nvidia Geforce RTX 3090", 1500)
}

store = {
    1: ("Samsung 970 EVO plus", 100),
    2: ("Samsung 980 PRO", 300),
    3: ("Seagate Barracuda Compute", 50),
    4: ("Kingston A400", 25),
    5: ("Seagate Ironwolf PRO", 500)
}

ram = {
    1: ("Crucial BallistiX", 40),
    2: ("Corsair Vengance Pro RGB", 80),
    3: ("Tiden Z RGB", 152),
    4: ("G.Skills Ripjaws V", 262),
    5: ("ADATA XPG LANCER RGB", 300)
}

cooler = {
    1: ("NZXT Kraken X53", 100),
    2: ("Noctua NHD-15", 90),
    3: ("ASUS ROG StiX", 240),
}

cases = {
    1: ("NZXT H510 ELITE", 150),
    2: ("Lian LI 011 Dynamic", 208),
    3: ("Corsair Carbide", 50)
}

def choice( menu ):
    for k,v in menu.items():
        print( f"{k}: {v[0]} \u00a3{v[1]}" )
    val = int(input("Make your choice by number:" ))
    print( f"You have chosen the {menu[val][0]} for \u00a3{menu[val][1]}" )


menu_choice=input("What would you like to buy today? [1: CPU's] [2: GPU's] [3: Storage] [4: RAM] [5: CPU Cooler] [6: Cases] [7: One of each] [Type the number that you want.]: ")

if menu_choice not in "12345678":
    print("You did not choose something or put in the wrong number.")
    exit()

if menu_choice in "17":
    print("Choose your CPU.:")
    c = choice(cpu)
if menu_choice in "27":
    print("GPU's, press enter to go to the next product:")
    c = choice(gpu)
if menu_choice in "37":
    print("Storage, press enter to go to the next product:")
    c = choice(store)
if menu_choice in "47":
    print("RAM, press enter to go to the next product:")
    c = choice(ram)
if menu_choice in "57":
    c = choice(cooler)
if menu_choice in "67":
    c = choice(cases)
```